# Showing $\int e^{x^2} dx = \frac12 \sqrt\pi \operatorname{erfi}(x) + C$

Tags: calculus, integration

Showing $\int e^{x^2} dx = \frac12 \sqrt\pi \operatorname{erfi}(x) + C$

I have seen this identity, but how is it reached?

What parts of it make sense and what part is just made into erf?

Comment: What is the definition of $erfi$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: That's basically the definition of the error function. Nothing to reach, just say "this commonly encountered transcendental integral will now be called the eroor function".

Comment: A downvote for wanting to expand my knowledge, how *dare* I care about *understanding* things

Comment: The `C` part makes 'sense', the rest just comes from the definition of the error function.

Comment: @MicroVirus what about the pi and half?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so much an identity as it is a definition. The Gaussian integral is often encountered in mathematics and physics, and has no analytic solution in terms of 'regular' functions (combinations of polynomials, exponentials, logarithms, trigonometric functions, etc.). So, why not give a name to this?

Following the definition of the $\operatorname{erfi}$, as given in the [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) in the comments:
$$\operatorname{erfi}(x) = -i\operatorname{erfi}(ix) = \frac{-2i}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{ix} e^{-t^2} dt $$

Then a change of variables inside the integral from $t \rightarrow i \tau $ yields:
$$ \operatorname{erfi}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{x} e^{\tau^2} d\tau $$

From this you can see where the expression for your integral comes from, and in particular where the factor of $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ comes from: it is in the definition of the error function.